# Is it possible to convert integers to time intervals in a Pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, database, pivot-table

This is my pivot DataFrame:

```py
Name            Tutor     Student
Date
2021-04-12        310         112
2021-04-13        394         210
2021-04-14        357           3
2021-04-15        359           0
2021-04-16        392           0
2021-04-17        307           0
2021-04-18        335           0
2021-04-19          0         121
```

The values under the Tutor and Student columns are integers representing the number of seconds.
Is it possible to convert these values to time intervals like Python's `datetime.timedelta`?

Comment: Can you please add desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear for the output you are looking for.

We can leverage pd.to_timedelta() method to convert seconds to timedelta.

**Solution**

```
df.iloc[:].apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s')
```

(Considering you want all columns in df to be converted to time_delta, if not please use df.loc with column names)

**Dry run on provided input:**

**Input**

```
Name    Tutor   Student
Date        
2021-04-12  310 112
2021-04-13  394 210
2021-04-14  357 3
2021-04-15  359 0
2021-04-16  392 0
2021-04-17  307 0
2021-04-18  335 0
2021-04-19  0   121
```

**Output**

```
Name               Tutor    Student
Date        
2021-04-12  0 days 00:05:10 0 days 00:01:52
2021-04-13  0 days 00:06:34 0 days 00:03:30
2021-04-14  0 days 00:05:57 0 days 00:00:03
2021-04-15  0 days 00:05:59 0 days 00:00:00
2021-04-16  0 days 00:06:32 0 days 00:00:00
2021-04-17  0 days 00:05:07 0 days 00:00:00
2021-04-18  0 days 00:05:35 0 days 00:00:00
2021-04-19  0 days 00:00:00 0 days 00:02:01
```

Comment: I've just noticed one issue with the results - the intervals seem to have been reduced to fractions of a second. E.g. 210 seconds should become 00:03:30 and in the result above it is 00:00:00.000000210.

Comment: Let me modify it, we can pass unit as seconds. Please check if it gives desired result.

Comment: That does the trick! Alternative syntax: `pd.to_timedelta, unit='s')`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df["Tutor"]   = pd.to_datetime(df["Tutor"], unit='s').dt.time
df["Student"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Student"], unit='s').dt.time
```

Result:

```
    Name        Tutor       Student
1   2021-04-12  00:05:10    00:01:52
2   2021-04-13  00:06:34    00:03:30
3   2021-04-14  00:05:57    00:00:03
4   2021-04-15  00:05:59    00:00:00
5   2021-04-16  00:06:32    00:00:00
6   2021-04-17  00:05:07    00:00:00
7   2021-04-18  00:05:35    00:00:00
8   2021-04-19  00:00:00    00:02:01
```

Comment: In my case there may be multiple student columns and their names are dynamic so perhaps referencing specific columns might not be feasible here. But I would actually prefer `to_datetime` or a custom function so it's still a very useful answer. Thank you, Merlin!